# How can I remove shortcuts in Cinnamon?

Tags: shortcuts, delete, cinnamon

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Cinnamon. How can I remove shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click the shortcut you are presented a pop-up menu allowing you to *remove* the shortcut:

[image]

Comment: It worked. My system was just broken so it didn't even show up.